# How to identify which Integration/ Token was used to access our NetSuite RESTlet Service?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In NetSuite, We plan to develop some RESTlets services for some External systems, and We want to manage different Integration for various systems, At the same time, We want to use one role.

So we want to know if any function exists that We can identify which Integration/ Token was used to access our NetSuite RESTlet Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token name and application from the login audit trail. You'd have to correlate the access times since this would be more of an implicit match. If you are just trying to get bulk usage this would be the way to go.

You could use a different role for each integration. The roles would likely only differ by name but logging the roles if they were used that way would work.

I don't think there is anything in the N/runtime module that would help with this directly.

Answer (score 0):

you want to know going back in the past or in the future?  If you are developing something new for the future and need extra information in the request (about the requestor) then you could you make your API (i.e. your Restlet) require that extra information. For a restlet that extra information will have to be specified as a parameter (not a header).

Inside your restlet you can do whatever you want with that parameter(as you probably know):

- send to a custom record
- hit your logging service
- etc

If you're stuck because you cannot change the request (someone else is developing it and you are just doing the netsuite side) then you could use a proxy for each request. That proxy could be an external system or it could be a suitelet -- a new proxy/suitelet for each "application" but accessible to the same user/role. The suitelet can passthrough the request and then pass through the response, but that's obviously extra work.